# In the singularity prior to the big bang where time doesn't exist, if something is possible (making a big bang) will it eventually happen?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, astrophysics, big-bang

If there was no time prior to the big bang and it was possible that it expanded and created the universe (and it happened) then, despite time doesn't exist there, if something is possible it will happen?

Answer (score 0):

As no one can say for sure, I will speculate, instead of voting to close down the question, because the question is a natural quest irrespective of how it has been worded, which, the members who pretend not to understand, can easily improvise.

In the case of primordial singularity there is no one to measure the time. There is no observable event that can be used to measure (or even define) time.
However, some unobservable/unmeasurable action must be going on with the singularity, that action eventually resulted in big bang. Due to physics limitations, we can not describe that "action", or whatever you call that in absence of time.

Taking a very simplistic analogy Suppose you hang a heavy rock with a rope and leave it there for years. Suppose, you do not have means to observe weakening of the rope. Then one day all of a sudden, you will see that the rope breaks and the rock falls down. Suppose you can observe the falling/fallen rock and breaking/broken rope.

Suppose this scenario was your whole universe, then you can say that there was no time/event/action for years (how you measure years?) and all of a sudden the the rock fell. Breaking of the rope Falling of the rock in this scenario is big bang for you.